# I can't install pip module

Tags: python, module, pip

When I try to install Selenium module with `pip install selenium` I get this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install selenium': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Do the programs `c:\python39\python.exe` and `C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe` exist on your computer?

Comment: C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe exist but c:\python39\python.exe doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following?

```
$ python -m pip install selenium
```

Comment: Tnx this work but why i have to add "python -m" to beginning

Comment: Great to know it works. I guess it is trying to say that the pip and python that we are using are coming from the same 'bin'. You may accept my answer if you like it.;)